# Raspberry Pi Zero W and the IRLZ34N MOSFET

Tags: pi-zero

I am trying to create this little circuit on my raspberry pi 4 zero w. The function of this circuit is to light up an SMD5050 strip using an IRLZ34N

I am using this tutorial https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/

My problem is the LEDs are very dim.

I have swapped the IRLZ34N with several others but they all produce dim leds

I did notice that when I unplugged the jumper off the GPIO I did touch the jumper lead and the LEDS suddenly became fully bright. Touching the jumper wuickly seems to turn the LEDS on or off.

So why can't the Pi Zero W does this with the GPIO?

The gate voltage for the IRLZ34N is 3.3v max and the Pi Zero is outputting 3.28v max, so why do the LEDS not become bright when plugged into the GPIO but do so when touching the jumper lead to the MOSFET gate.
Thanks

Comment: Have you asked this question to the author of the "tutorial"? If so, what was his answer?

Comment: If you can't get an answer from him: 1. **Measure** the voltages across the D-S junction and the G-S junction of the MOSFET when the lights are on 2. Same measurement when the lights are off. 3, Since our license for mind-reading has expired here, please explain what you mean exactly by "touch the jumper lead"... touch it to what... with what.

Comment: You forgot to include "this little circuit" in your question. Considering it's not working, I'm not convinced it is the same as in the tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Your PI may be supplying high enough gate voltage but not enough current to fulfill the *gate charge* sufficient to turn it on robustly. Remember the gate acts like a big capacitor that must be fully charged to turn the mosfet fully on. Picture trying to fill a large bucket on a Rube Goldberg teter-totter lever with a squirt gun from 3.3 meters away. The squirt gun is powerful enough to squirt far enough easily (pressure=voltage) but will take forever and might even run dry before the job is100% done. A water hose is really needed for best results. So use the PI to drive a small transistor that'll be fed from a solid power supply, and the transistor feeds the mosfet gate... Which btw, CC an handle 16v, the 3.3v you quoted is for the max(expected upper limit) gate threshold a
Which is the level where the mosfet just starts turning on enough to note on a graph. An IRLZ34N will really be solidly full on with closer to 5v at the gate above the source. Unless it's one of those Alibaba counterfeit transistors then it might need maybe 10-12v